# Implement a text highlighting feature in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, sorting, split

I have a task to create API using ExpressJS that will manage highlights which will be made on the frontend. How can I keep track of **my highlighted text** if someone updates a part of the text?

I was keeping the three starting and ending characters of the highlighted text. But a problem is, how will I manage those characters if the text is edited.

```
const { textH, allText } = req.body;
let chars = { };
const enclosingChars = (hLighted, theString) => {
  let startingChars = null, endingChars = null;
  const index = theString.indexOf(hLighted);
  const last3 = index + hLighted.length;
  if ((index - 3) > -1) startingChars = theString.substring(index - 3, index);
  if ((index + 3) <= theString.length) endingChars = theString.substring(last3, last3 + 3);
  return { startingChars, endingChars };
};
if (allText.includes(textH)) {
  chars = enclosingChars(textH, allText);
}
chars.hLighted = textH;
```

If a part of the highlighted text is edited, I will delete the highlighted in my storage. If not, I want to check if my **starting and ending characters** have changed, then I change them accordingly. 
But I don't know how to get that highlighted text if its index changed

Comment: You could choose to store both the start and end characters like you've been doing as well as as start and end point in the string.  Then, when the user updates the text, you simply shift the highlight start and stop location based on the edits to the text.  So if the string was `The quick brown fox` and `quick` was highlighted, you could store `(4,8)` and then if the user changes the text to `The red quick brown fox`, the position would be shifted by 4 to `(8,12)`.  Obviously you'd shift the highlighted items one index at a time based on key input

Comment: why are you matching the three starting and ending characters instead of the whole word?

Comment: @MichaelPlatt, I thought about this but I failed to implement it. How will I capture **the new indexes of highlighted tex**

Comment: It can get a bit complicated but the 1000 foot view would be to have a change listener on the component that can change and would contain highlighted words.  When there is a change, you can check where the change occurred and then increment or decrement the index of the highlighted word accordingly.

Comment: @AkimanaAjoullyJeand'Amour *"**If a part of the highlighted text is edited**, I will delete the highlighted in my storage. **If not**, I want to check if my starting and ending characters have changed, then I change them accordingly. "* Emphasis is mine. If text isn't edited...why are you checking to see if it changed? Are implying that text highlighted is different from non-highlighted text? If so then you might be mired in minutiae.

Comment: @zfrisch, I found out that my implementation will fail if those characters changed too

Comment: I'm having a hard time following. Would you be able to post an example of how it is working now using dummy data?

Answer (score 0):

so it will be not as easy as you think if you consider keeping track of edits outside of the highlighted text.

1. the text might contain more than one similar phrase/word (to the highlighted)
2. the newly inserted phrase might be similar to the highlighted one (worse if before the main one in terms of indices)

so if any of the above scenarios happens the indices will be of no use because you can fall to the wrong text

Do the following

a. when highlighting keep the following
       1. the content : to make sure if the edit happens in there, you know it and you can act accordingly

```
   2. keep track of the index range of your text even in case the shift is required (when the text before it is edited)

   3. take a screenshot of the entire article and store it so that when an edit to the article happens you know exactly which part is edited. this will require to check word by word and see if any word in the new text is different from the word of the same index in the old (screenshot). and you can shift the ranges of the highlighted text accordingly.
```

Remember any edit that happens after the highlighted text is innocuous.
Hope this helps.